# Redirect every link that starts with

Tags: redirect

is it possible to make my website redirect every link that starts with something like ​

> /nl​/products/motors​/

to just

> /motors/

even when a link has something like

> /nl/products/motors/allotherinfo/moreinfo/ect./

to redirect something like this to

> /motors/

at the moment i get loads of 404 errors because i changed my website and i think this is not good for my google rankings.

Thanks for taking the time to read this,

Sjoerd

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code in .htaccess file

```
Redirect ^/nl​/products/motors​/.*$ /motors/
```

So here if you url will match /nl/products/motors/ then it will redirect to /motors/

Answer (score -1):

Redirect rule if the URL contains a certain word?
Please try with the code below:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} motors
RewriteRule .* motors
```

Comment: That would be an infinite loop.